# ActiveRecord joining nested associations on non default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Before you ask, I have no control over creating any views or join tables in the database I'm working with.

I found in the ActiveRecord docs where you can do multi-level joining:

```
12.2.4 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

Category.joins(articles: [{ comments: :guest }, :tags])
This produces:

SELECT categories.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
  INNER JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
  INNER JOIN guests ON guests.comment_id = comments.id
  INNER JOIN tags ON tags.article_id = articles.id
```

And where you can specify what to join on

```
Client.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON addresses.client_id = clients.id')
```

What I want to do is something that combines the 2

```
Client.joins('Inner Join addresses on addresses.client_name = client.name').joins('Inner Join state on state.abreviation = addresses.state_abreviation)
```

or in raw sql

```
Select client.* from client 
Inner Join addresses on client.client_name = addresses.client_name
Inner Join state on addresses.state_abreviation = state.abreviation
```

and If I can do this using associations instead of joins that would be great!:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  has_one :guest
end

class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: Looks like there is `addresses` table and associated model that you have omitted here. Is that correct?

Comment: @San I included what I was looking for "What I want to do is something that combines the 2"

Comment: You describe Active record models with associations, that different from tables and models that you wrote in your second joins request. This is confusing, and does not match Active Record pattern

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer.  You need to define the foreign_key for the table so you can map it back.

```
  belongs_to :addresses, foreign_key: 'state_abreviation'
```

Comment: Users could not understand your answer, because at question you didn't describe your database structure

Comment: Good work, you looked at the rails manual :) ....aaand that's just the beginning of your problems :) Try playing with queries and more complex scopes

Comment: to extend on this, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685837/activerecord-includes-not-working-with-foreign-keys

Answer (score 3):

Using Arel:

```
c = Client.arel_table
a = Adress.arel_table
s = State.arel_table
query = Client.all.arel
         .join(a)
           .on(a[:client_name].eq(c[:client_name]))
         .join(s)
           .on(s[:abreviation].eq(a[:state_abreviation]))
Client.find_by_sql(query.to_sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'through'
for your Category model these will be like this

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments, through: :articles
  has_many :tags, through: :articles
end

Category.last.tags
=> tags
Category.last.articles
=> articles
```

Comment: This does not solve my issue at all.  I am looking for how to do custom column associations

Comment: I wrote answer for db schema, that you described