# ActiveRecord includes not working with foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having a hard time getting table associations to work properly.  I have 2 classes (tables) that I need to associate with each other.

```
class CaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'seq_id'
    has_many :model, foreign_key: 'model_seq_id'
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'seq_id'
  self.table_name = 'model'

  belongs_to :case_model, foreign_key: 'seq_id'
  scope :with_case_info, ->{includes(:case_model)}
end
```

When I run `Model.with_case_info` I get the following SQL:

```
SELECT "CASE_MODEL".* FROM "CASE_MODEL"  WHERE "CASE_MODEL"."SEQ_ID" IN (results from above sql)
```

What i'm looking for is

```
SELECT "CASE_MODEL".* FROM "CASE_MODEL"  WHERE "CASE_MODEL"."MODEL_SEQ_ID" IN (results from above sql)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pointing to the wrong foreign key in your `Model` class.  The following is correct.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'seq_id'
  self.table_name = 'model'

  belongs_to :case_model, foreign_key: 'model_seq_id'
  scope :with_case_info, ->{includes(:case_model)}
end
```

On a `belongs_to`, you're saying that the foreign key is on this model.  Based on the `has_many` in `CaseModel`, the foreign key is `model_seq_id`, so `Model` should use the same foreign key.

Comment: Now I'm getting something completely wrong

CASE_MODEL"."SEQ_ID" IN (0)

Comment: Ah, try setting the `primary_key` option on both sides of the relationship to point to the correct primary key.  By default, it assumes `id` is the primary key, but that's not the case here.

Comment: `belongs_to :case_model, foreign_key: 'model_seq_id', primary_key: 'seq_id'`, etc.

Comment: so I can set different primary_keys for each foreign key to "link" with?  So it's `belongs_to: table, foreign_key: my_column, primary_key: your_column and then on the other table :has_many: first_table

Comment: Yeah, but you'll also have to set the same options on the `has_many :first_tables, foreign_key: 'my_column', primary_key: 'your_column'`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you are manually specifying the `primary` and `foreign` keys. You can simply use `has_many` and `belongs_to` and ensure that the `Model`'s table has a `case_model_id` field and it will work automatically.

Comment: That's not always possible when you're working with legacy data.

Comment: as @SeanHill said, i'm working with legacy data and cannot modify the table schema

Comment: Gotcha, the way it was phrased made me think it was a fresh addition.